# Ripple : local File not loading

Tags: cordova, ripple

I have created a new project with apache cordova

`create MyFolder com.mydomain.HelloWorld HelloWorld`

Now the www forlder of the created app is in Z:\cordova\MyFolder\www
Therefore I launched `Z:\cordova\MyFolder\www\index.html`  in my updated google chrome browser. The *Ripple* extension is installed. BUT when I click on `enable`, nothing is working. Also I know ripple is working as I was able to use it for www.google.com.
My guess is that since the address is a file path, ripple fails to play its role. Am I right ?

I'm guessing that if I was able to launch my page with and address like

`localhost\cordova\MyFolder\www\index.html` it would work. How could I do that if this can help ?  Or what do you guyz think I did not set properly for the file path to be reconised by ripple ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was right. The problem was that Ripple needs the address to be from a web server (local, or remote). So ripple won't work with localfiles. The only thing you have to do (for chrome) download a local web server app here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjs5vrGhN3MAhWBtBoKHeD_BecQFgggMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fweb-server-for-chrome%2Fofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNGq7SsFXX75eQeHGhkTldvA0Xqhdg   . Alternatively, you can download Apache and set it up on your machine